# In Jquery Mobile How to make the multi div to center of the Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

[image]

Now I'm currently getting this to leftside of the page I want to make this to center of the page.

HTML :

```
<div id="viewMe">       
      <div class="leftelement">
          <div class="leftelement Width150">
              <a href="page1.html">
                <span class="image1">&#32;</span>
                <span>Image 1</span>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="leftelement Width150">
              <a href="page2.html">
                <span class="image2">&#32;</span>
                <span>Image 2</span>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="leftelement Width150">
              <a href="page3.html">
                <span class="image3">&#32;</span>
                <span>Image 3</span>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.leftelement{float:left;}
.Width150 {width:150px;}
.image1 {background: url(../images/image1.png) no-repeat;height: 160px;width: 145px;display:block;}
.image2 {background: url(../images/image2.png) no-repeat;height: 160px;width: 145px;display:block;}
.image3 {background: url(../images/image3.png) no-repeat;height: 160px;width: 145px;display:block;}
```

Comment: #viewMe {margin: auto; width: 450px;}

Comment: I hope im understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Hi eskimo thanks, Here the problem is I can't set the width to main div. Because i'm going to use the code for android & iOS. in case of ipad it remains at width 450px not at full width it remians left to page not at center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for, using a combination of css tweaks I've modified your code so the items float in the center without the need for applying a width to the containing div

```
    text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BSPVM/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I want the icon next to next not one by one.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Let's try this.

Comment: replace display:inline-block; instead of display:inline-table; it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code for mobiles - you should know about the [`box`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-align.asp) properties in `css3`:

```
#viewMe{
   display:box;
   box-orient:horizontal;
   box-pack:center;
   box-align:center;
}
```